# Update regex to select only some characterss

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
;ks;;;EAN;Cena v EUR/bez DPH;NC vź.dopravy/bez DPH;MOC vź.
 DPH;DPH;Skupina;Podskupina;KUS\r\n33113 1;3;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r
\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: gold metallic\r\noutisde: anthracite
 brushed\r\nH. 14 cm - B. 11,5 
cm\";7,95;4001250331131;218,625;262,35;579;21;0004;0001;KUS\r\n33114 
8;2;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: gold metallic\r
\noutisde: anthracite brushed\r\nH. 20 cm - B. 14 
cm\";15,95;4001250331148;438,625;526,35;1159;21;0004;0001;KUS\r\n33118
 6;3;\"windlight \"\"Feeling\"\"\r\nmetal, handmade\r\ninside: copper 
metallic\r\noutisde: anthracite brushed\r\nH. 14 cm - W. 11,5 
cm\";7,95;4001250331186;218,625;262,35;579;21;0004;0001;KUS\r\n
```

I have the following regex:

```
;\\"[^;]*\\";
```

But I want to have the result as (select only \r\n in the red rectangle, NOT others)

[image]

If anyone has any idea please EDIT my regex

Comment: You cannot do it that easily with regex, maybe you can achieve it another way? What should your final result look like?

Comment: @stribizhev The final result is text without \r\n in the some parts of text...

Comment: What's the criteria to pick one but ignore the others?

Comment: Did you try to use a CSV parser and delete linebreak in each field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=;\\"[^;]*)\\r\\n(?=[^;]*\\";)
```

You can use this.[See demo.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%3b%5c%5c%22%5b%5e%3b%5d*)%5c%5cr%5c%5cn(%3f%3d%5b%5e%3b%5d*%5c%5c%22%3b)&i=%3bks%3b%3b%3bEAN%3bCena+v+EUR%2fbez+DPH%3bNC+v%c5%ba.dopravy%2fbez+DPH%3bMOC+v%c5%ba.%0d%0a+DPH%3bDPH%3bSkupina%3bPodskupina%3bKUS%5cr%5cn33113+1%3b3%3b%5c%22windlight+%5c%22%5c%22Feeling%5c%22%5c%22%5cr%5cnmetal%2c+handmade%5cr%5cninside%3a+gold+metallic%5cr%5cnoutisde%3a+anthracite%0d%0a+brushed%5cr%5cnH.+14+cm+-+B.+11%2c5+%0d%0acm%5c%22%3b7%2c95%3b4001250331131%3b218%2c625%3b262%2c35%3b579%3b21%3b0004%3b0001%3bKUS%5cr%5cn33114+%0d%0a8%3b2%3b%5c%22windlight+%5c%22%5c%22Feeling%5c%22%5c%22%5cr%5cnmetal%2c+handmade%5cr%5cninside%3a+gold+metallic%5cr%0d%0a%5cnoutisde%3a+anthracite+brushed%5cr%5cnH.+20+cm+-+B.+14+%0d%0acm%5c%22%3b15%2c95%3b4001250331148%3b438%2c625%3b526%2c35%3b1159%3b21%3b0004%3b0001%3bKUS%5cr%5cn33118%0d%0a+6%3b3%3b%5c%22windlight+%5c%22%5c%22Feeling%5c%22%5c%22%5cr%5cnmetal%2c+handmade%5cr%5cninside%3a+copper+%0d%0ametallic%5cr%5cnoutisde%3a+anthracite+brushed%5cr%5cnH.+14+cm+-+W.+11%2c5+%0d%0acm%5c%22%3b7%2c95%3b4001250331186%3b218%2c625%3b262%2c35%3b579%3b21%3b0004%3b0001%3bKUS%5cr%5cn)

Comment: @Jane its a C# regex...it wont run there......try at `regexstorm.net` or `regexhero.net`

Comment: If you use the regex as a regular string literal, it is the same as `@"(?<=;"[^;]*)\r\n(?=[^;]*";)"` verbatim one. There is no need to escape quotes in regex.

Answer (score 1):

You can match the blocks from `"windlight` till the last non-escaped `"` and replace the `\r\n` in those blocks only with a match evaluator:

```
var s = "<YOUR_STRING>";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, "\"windlight[^\"](?:\"\"[^\"]*)*",
                          m => m.Value.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty));
```

The regex - `"windlight([^"](?:""[^"]*)*)` - matches `"windlight`, and then `""` or anything that is no `"` up to the closing `"`.

The result is:

```
;ks;;;EAN;Cena v EUR/bez DPH;NC vź.dopravy/bez DPH;MOC vź. DPH;DPH;Skupina;Podskupina;KUS
33113 1;3;"windlight ""Feeling""metal, handmadeinside: gold metallicoutisde: anthracite brushedH. 14 cm - B. 11,5 cm";7,95;4001250331131;218,625;262,35;579;21;0004;0001;KUS
33114 8;2;"windlight ""Feeling""metal, handmadeinside: gold metallicoutisde: anthracite brushedH. 20 cm - B. 14 cm";15,95;4001250331148;438,625;526,35;1159;21;0004;0001;KUS
33118 6;3;"windlight ""Feeling""metal, handmadeinside: copper metallicoutisde: anthracite brushedH. 14 cm - W. 11,5 cm";7,95;4001250331186;218,625;262,35;579;21;0004;0001;KUS
```

**UPDATE**

If you have literal `\r\n` (that is, in C# you see `\\r\\n` if you check the string in the popup), use

```
m.Value.Replace("\\r\\n", string.Empty)
                 ^^ ^^
```

Comment: I think it was not clear for me from the very start what you really have: line breaks, or `\r\n` as literal strings. Please check the update. `(?<=;\\"[^;]*)\\r\\n(?=[^;]*\\";)` is bound to fail sooner or later because it does not allow checking for escaped quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the regex? I suppose that you're actually trying to split the text to lines. Why not just do:

```
myLongString.split('\r\n')
```

to get a list of lines?

It seems like a terrible idea to make a regex to match just these selected newlines. Your data looks like CSV, maybe you just need a CSV parser? Using regex for such cases will make you regret it when you'll have to fix something in this code next month. You've been warned.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like so: `(?<=\p{L}|")\\r.?\\n(?=\p{L}|")` (example [here](https://regex101.com/r/xH5vH2/1)). This will look for `\r\n` characters which are preceeded by letters or quotation marks.